# Spawn child node process from Electron

Tags: node.js, electron, child-process

I have an existing node script that I run from CLI like `node script.js --args`.

I am trying to build an Electron app to replace the CLI. To run the actual script I can use `child_process`:

```
function run(arg) {
    const script = spawn("node", ["./script.js", "run", "--arg", arg], { cwd: TOOLS_DIR, env: process.env });

    script.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
    });

    script.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log(`stderr: ${data}`);
    });

    script.on('close', (code) => {
        console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
    });
}
```

However this only works when I launch `electron` from my app folder. When I run the built app using `electron-packager` the `run()` call fails with error:

```
Uncaught Error: spawn node ENOENT
```

It seems that the built app cannot run `node` commands. I have NodeJS installed but if I log `process.env.PATH` I notice that from the built app `/usr/local/bin` (where `node` lives) is not in the `$PATH`, but if I run `electron` from my app folder it is. In either case, since Electron runs on NodeJS is there an easy way to run a node script from an Electron app?

Comment: Are you trying to make an Electron app that starts a Node.JS application in scripts.js?

Comment: Basically, yes. My `script.js` actually starts up some docker images using `docker-compose`. I tried using `fork()` instead of `spawn()` and that worked to run the script without mucking with `env` but then I got `ENOENT` on `docker-compose` from in the script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For anyone interested, I eventually got it working in my case by using a combination of [`fork()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options) (which uses the Electron packaged NodeJS runtime instead of depending on NodeJS installed on client machine) and patching the `env`'s `$PATH` (to allow the `script.js` command to itself spawn some commands):

```
const env = { ...process.env, PATH: `${process.env.PATH}:/usr/local/bin` };
const child = fork("./script.js", args, { cwd: TOOLS_DIR, env, silent: true });
```

The incomplete `$PATH` is a known issue in Electron and there's the [`fix-path`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/fix-path) library as a solution, but I could not get that to work for some reason.

Comment: dude... u saved me!!!

Comment: save me too, dude.